# Assigning a reference type object a value on a secondary thread, and then working with this object from my primary thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates

I am trying to create a variable which is of type **MyReferenceTypeObject** and of value null on thread one, use a delegate to make this thread equal to a new instance of **MyReferenceTypeObject** on thread two, and then access members of **MyReferenceTypeObject** back on thread one (in the delegates callback method).

My code is below:

```
Module Module1

    Delegate Sub EditReferenceTypePropertyDelegate(ByVal referenceTypeObject As MyReferenceTypeObject, ByVal numberToChangeTo As Integer)

    Sub Main()

        Dim editReferenceDelegate = New EditReferenceTypePropertyDelegate(AddressOf EditReferenceTypeProperty)

        Dim newReferenceTypeObject As MyReferenceTypeObject
        editReferenceDelegate.BeginInvoke(newReferenceTypeObject, 2, AddressOf EditReferenceCallback, newReferenceTypeObject)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Sub EditReferenceTypeProperty(ByVal referenceTypeObject As MyReferenceTypeObject, ByVal numberToChangeTo As Integer)

        referenceTypeObject = New MyReferenceTypeObject()
        referenceTypeObject.i = numberToChangeTo

    End Sub

    Sub EditReferenceCallback(ByVal e As IAsyncResult)

        Dim referenceObject = DirectCast(e.AsyncState, MyReferenceTypeObject)
        Console.WriteLine(referenceObject)

    End Sub

End Module

Class MyReferenceTypeObject
    Public Property i As Integer
End Class
```

However, **newReferenceTypeObject** comes into my callback method as null. I think I understand why, but the problem is that I need to pull some data from a database which I then need to pass into the constructor of **newReferenceTypeObject**, this takes a couple of seconds, and I don't want to lock up my UI while this is happening. I want to create a field of type **MyReferenceTypeObject** on thread one, instantiate this on thread two (after I have pulled the data of the database to pass into the constructor) and then work with members of the object back on thread one once the instantiation is complete.

Is this possible? I am using VB.Net with .Net 4.0 on Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: To clarify: You want to instantiate an Object of type X (Which requires data from a DB) in another thread and have it back on the GUI thread once its done with the querying / instantiation?

Comment: That's correct, I threw together a simple example to help explain, if this has made the question more complicated I will take it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the GUI responsive during a long running action, I'd consider using the `Task<>` library (Comes with `.NET 4.0`). Here's a quick example.

```
Sub Main()

        Dim instantiateTask = New Task(Of MyReferenceTypeObject)(Function()
                                                                     ' Call your database to pull the instantiation data.
                                                                     Return New MyReferenceTypeObject With {.i = 2}
                                                                 End Function)

        instantiateTask.Start() ' Start the task -> invokes a ThreadPool.Thread to do the work.
         instantiateTask.ContinueWith(Sub(x)
                                     Console.WriteLine(x.Result.I)
                                 End Sub, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
    End Sub
```

.`Wait` blocks the GUI thread. However, you could use `ContinueWith` which is async and therefor nonblocking. Also you need to provide the `TaskScheduler` ( `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContex`t ) from the GUI thread to prevent cross-thread exceptions in case you want to update the UI from within the async method.

Comment: So `InstantiateTask.Wait` doesn't lock up my UI?

Comment: I've changed the sample a little bit to make it non-blocking.